# How to use grouping in this query

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am using mongo morphia. How to add group by clause in this below function.

```
public ArrayList<DeliveryServiceVisitorUserTraceEntity> listExpectedDeliveries(String associationId) {

        // HashMap<String, String> filterExpressions = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Query<DeliveryServiceVisitorUserTraceEntity> query = DBManager.getInstance().createQuery(
                DeliveryServiceVisitorUserTraceEntity.class);

        List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        values.add(1);
        values.add(2);

        query.and(query.criteria("associationId").equal(associationId),
                query.criteria("deliveryServicestatus").in(values),
                query.criteria("allowTimeIn").greaterThan(getStartOfDay(new Date()) + ""), query
                        .criteria("allowTimeIn").lessThan(getEndOfDay(new Date()) + "")
                        );
        List<DeliveryServiceVisitorUserTraceEntity> residents = query.asList();
        return new ArrayList<DeliveryServiceVisitorUserTraceEntity>(residents);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use aggregation framework to achieve grouping.
I use morphia 1.1.0 and for aggregation I would do something like this

```html
AggregationPipeline pipeline = DAO.getDatastore()
      .createAggregation(DeliveryServiceVisitorUserTraceEntity.class)
      .match(query) //Your createQuery object
      .group("groupByField"); //group by field
        
 Iterator<GroupObj> iterator = pipeline.aggregate(GroupObj.class);
```

Here GroupObj is the new class you need to create which would match the schema of the aggregation result